# MVC save to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How to correctly save to database? I have the following but not working. I am using a custom `ModelMetadata` (`ORDERMetadata`) and setting it equal to the `.edmx` / `order.cs` model and trying to save it.

The key field in `Order.cs` model is `[OrderID]`, but I am passing `[model.Order_Number]` which is unique value. I am currently, not passing `[OrderID]` in `ORDERMetadata` model. Is this required?

`Order.cs`:

```
public partial class ORDER
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int Order_Number { get; set; }
    public string Order_Type { get; set; }
}
```

`ORDERMetadata` model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ORDERMetadata))]
public partial class ORDER
{
    // Blank. It's just here to add the class-level attribute.
}

public class ORDERMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Order Number")]
    public int Order_Number { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Order Type")]
    public string Order_Type { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ORDERMetadata model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    try
    {
        // update order
        ORDER order = new ORDER();
        order.Order_Number = model.Order_Number;

        order.Order_Type = model.Order_Type;

        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.UpdateResult = "Order updated!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: When updating you should use an existing entity, but you're creating a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

ORDER order = db.ORDERS.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Order_Number == model.Order_Number);